# Java Rest Service: 404 required to be thrown if the URL is not an exact match of Path set

Tags: java, rest

I am exposing a JAVA REST service (Using Apache-CXF + Jetty). I am using the following code:

```
@Path("/service/{userid}")
public class RestService{

   @GET
   @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public ReturnObject process(@PathParam("userid" String userId)){
       // App Code
   }
}
```

When I hit the URL pattern `http://<hostname:port>/service/john` , the `proccess` method is getting invoked and the application response is sent.

But when i hit the URL pattern `http://<hostname:port>/service/john/johny`,  the browser is not receiving any response back.

Below is the log. As I have not configured for this path. shouldn't it return  a 404 response. Why it is considering this as a relative path ?

```
No operation matching request path "/service/john/johny" is found, Relative Path: /johny, HTTP Method: GET, ContentType: */*, Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,image/webp,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8,. Please enable FINE/TRACE log level for more details.
```

Comment: Working as intended. `@Path("/service/{userid}")` matches `/service/john` but not `/service/john/johny`. I believe you will need a different method signature to extract two path variables - annotated with something like:

`@Path("/service/{var1}/{var2}")`

Comment: @TheHeadRush I understand that.I don't need the second variable. My question is, shouldn't the Rest Service framework respond with a 404, as the request is not an exact match ?

Comment: Gotcha, i must have skimmed the post instead of reading it carefully. My bad.